# How do I properly configure Internet Explorer Connection Settings via Group Policy?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, internet-explorer

I've configured the location of our automatic configuration script under "User Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Internet Settings > Internet Explorer 8 > Connections > LAN Settings > Use automatic configuration script", but when I look at the configured settings in Internet Options, the path is not shown and the checkbox is not ticked.

Have I configured this setting in the recommended location in Group Policy?  Any idea why it's having no effect?

Comment: You should post this on superuser.

Comment: @i-CONICA No, this question is appropriate for SF

Comment: @squillman Clearly... I thought it might get more attention from the audience of superuser.

Comment: @i-CONICA, Is it possible to migrate a question to the Super User community... because so far, I haven't received any possible answers.  :(

Comment: @MattyBrown It is, the moderators can migrate questions, but if they think it's appropriate here you'll be out of luck. I'd just post it on Super User as well, at least that way you've more chance of a solution.

Comment: Run Group Policy Results and Group Policy Modeling and report back the results.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the preference you need to press F6 to turn the red dotted line into green, in this way your setting will be applied.